# Retrieving data from appsettings.json

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, dependency-injection

So I'm really stuck for 2 days. I've been searching trough stackoverflow and google following many guides but non that helped :/. So I'm trying to retrieve data from the appsettings json file as i will store data in there as my standard settings file.

I want to read a json array-> iv' called my section "Locations" and my key "Location" where my values is an json array. For the moment there are only car company names in that array not the real data. The real data are filepaths.

I'm using vs2017 with .net core 2.0 or 2.1

```
public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
{
    Configuration = configuration;
}

public IConfiguration Configuration { get; set; }

// This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddMvc()
        .AddJsonOptions(config =>
        {
            config.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();
        });
    services.AddOptions();
    services.AddSingleton<IConfiguration>(Configuration);


}

// This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
        .SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath)
        .AddEnvironmentVariables()
        .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
        .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true);

    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseBrowserLink();
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();

    }
    else
    {
        app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
    }

    app.UseStaticFiles();

    app.UseMvc(routes =>
    {
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "default",
            template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
    });

    Configuration = builder.Build();
}
```

This is my startup class.

```
"Locations": {
    "Location": [ "Ford", "BMW", "Fiat" ]
},
```

my json.

```
namespace MediaCenter.Models
{
    public class Locations
    {
        public List<string> location { get; set; }
    }
}
```

My class for it since I read that it's needed for .net core 2.0 for the DI system.

```
public IActionResult Settings()
{
    var array = _configuration.GetSection("Locations").GetSection("Location");
    var items = array.Value.AsEnumerable();
    return View();
}
```

my controller data.

For the record when i make a breakpoint at "var array" i can see in the providers and members that my values are stored within so i guess i'm not making the proper call to the array? anayways it would really help if I get a good working asnwer since i'm stuck :(.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple things wrong.

1. In your startup you need to configure `Configuration` in your
   constructor not in the `ConfigureServices(services)`.
2. They are stored as `Children`, so you need to do `GetChildren()` on
   your section.

Here is what you need to change in `Startup.cs`

```
// Replace IConfiguration with IHostingEnvironment since we will build
// Our own configuration
public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
        .SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath)
        .AddEnvironmentVariables()
        .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
        .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true);

    // Set the new Configuration
    Configuration = builder.Build();
}
```

In your controller you can now use the following:

```
public IActionResult Settings()
{
   var array = Configuration.GetSection("Locations:Location")
       .GetChildren()
       .Select(configSection => configSection.Value);
   return View();
}
```

**Edit**

Problem is that the appsettings.json is formatted incorrectly. Everything was configured as a child of the `Logging` Section. Below is the updated and correct json, I added an extra `},` and removed `}` from the bottom.

```
 {
  "Logging": {
    "IncludeScopes": false,
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Warning"
    }
  },

  "DBConnection": {
    "Host": "",
    "UserName": "",
    "Password": ""
  },

  "Locations": {
    "Location": [ "Ford", "BMW", "Fiat" ]
  },

  "VideoExtensions": {
    "Extensions": []
  }
}
```

Comment: well it was a great tought but still null. Is everything oke in my startup class?

Comment: @TimClinckemalie You are correct your startup class was wrong too, see my edited answer!

Comment: I still have problems, i have put it in the startup but still getting "null" :/
Sorry if its too lot too ask still learning tough.

code: https://pastebin.com/Z7smP40a

Comment: @TimClinckemalie I just made a new project with only your code in it and it works for me not sure what the problem might be.. Perhaps you can upload the whole project to github?

Comment: my project is uploaded on my private gitlab server but i might be able to migrate it to a public github

Comment: @TimClinckemalie Well I found the problem, your appsetting.json is formatted wrong everything was a child of `"logging"` I don't think that is supposed to be the case. I'll add the edited json in my answer!

Comment: ow that I didn't see haha that explains alot of course why every guide isn't working. a helping hand is always working thx alot bro :) wow yeah i see that now, i have put my '}' wrong. everything was indeed inside "logging" great haha thx anyway

Answer (score 0):

For `WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder` in `Program.cs`, there is no need to use `new ConfigurationBuilder()`. Try options below:

**Option1** Get value from `IConfiguration`

```
    public class OptionsController : Controller
{
    private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;

    public OptionsController(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        _configuration = configuration;
    }
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        var locations = new Locations();
        _configuration.GetSection("Locations").Bind(locations);

        var items = locations.location.AsEnumerable();
        return View();
    }
}
```

**Options** Configure `Options` in `Startup`

1. Startup.cs

   ```
           services.Configure<Locations>(Configuration.GetSection("Locations"));
   ```
2. Use in Controller

   ```
   public class OptionsController : Controller
   {
   private readonly Locations _locations;
   public OptionsController(IOptions<Locations> options)
   {
       _locations = options.Value;
   }
   public IActionResult Index()
   {           
       var items2 = _locations;
       return View();
   }
    }
   ```

[Source Code](https://github.com/Edward-Zhou/AspNetCore/blob/aa589e2ae1e4feb3635c2093d08002e2ec611671/OptionsPro/Controllers/OptionsController.cs#L12)

Comment: well it's still "null" for me when i put a breakpoint. Or I am doing something completly wrong or I have no clue.

Comment: @TimClinckemalie Have you downloaded the source code to make a test?

Comment: yes but still "null" when i look at _location it says empty array. but never the less maybe will leave it here. i have found many guides here and on google and as mucha s you guys try to help me it doesn't seem to work. So i just use a db instead that might be even better than the appsettings but thx anyway

Comment: @TimClinckemalie Could you share us a screen shot about your `_locations`?

Comment: @TimClinckemalie The screen shot seems to be your own project. Do download my project instead of copying the source code?

Comment: jup your project is working but only the  "items" variable the "items2" variable is null for me. thx for the help i'll see what the difference our between our porjects on the other hand since i already tried your code in my project i think my project is corrupt or something. Buit thanks all for the help  :)

Comment: @TimClinckemalie What do you mean by `items2`?